# round number by excess in javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

Is there any method in Javascript that rounds the number by excess like for example:

5.3 = 6

10.7 = 11

1.1 = 2

Like every time the number after the comma is bigger than 0 we round up the number.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called `Math.ceil()`:

```
var x = 5.3;
alert(Math.ceil(x)); // 6
```

The name "ceil" is an abbreviation of "ceiling".  The opposite function is `Math.floor()`.  Both of those functions operate according to magnitude. Sometimes, you want to work either "away from zero" or "towards zero", so you'd have to check for that specifically. (That is, `Math.ceil(-2.1)` is -2, not -3.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes ,   `Math.ceil()` function can do this , for more information about Math functions [check this link](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathfunc.htm).

**Example :**

```
 Alert(Math.ceil(5.3));//alert 6
```

**Other examples :**

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
  document.write('ceil(-3.8) = ' + Math.ceil(-3.8) + '<BR>');
  document.write('ceil(-3.5) = ' + Math.ceil(-3.5) + '<BR>');
  document.write('ceil(-3.2) = ' + Math.ceil(-3.2) + '<BR>');
  document.write('ceil(-3) = ' + Math.ceil(-3) + '<BR>');
  document.write('ceil(3) = ' + Math.ceil(3) + '<BR>');
  document.write('ceil(3.2) = ' + Math.ceil(3.2) + '<BR>');
  document.write('ceil(3.5) = ' + Math.ceil(3.5) + '<BR>');
  document.write('ceil(3.8) = ' + Math.ceil(3.8) + '<BR>');
</SCRIPT>
```

**Output:**

```
ceil(-3.8) = -3
ceil(-3.5) = -3
ceil(-3.2) = -3
ceil(-3) = -3
ceil(3) = 3
ceil(3.2) = 4
ceil(3.5) = 4
ceil(3.8) = 4
```